# How to retrieve Cognito token from AuthCognitoTokensProvider using swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have successfully integrated Amplify into my project. This has helped me to sign up, sign In and also sign out. Now I need a way to retrieve the Cognito token so I can use it to make api calls with in my app. Unfortunately that hasn't worked I get the bellow error when I try to cast my session from my Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession method. And also I'm able to get the isSignedIn status. > cast session Optional(AmplifyPlugins.AWSAuthCognitoSession(isSignedIn: true, userSubResult: Swift.Result<Swift.String, Amplify.AuthError>.failure(AuthError: Unexpected error occurred with message: An unknown error occurred Recovery suggestion: This should not happen. There is a possibility that there is a bug if this error persists. Please take a look at

> Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=5 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException, message=Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool.}), identityIdResult: Swift.Result<Swift.String, Amplify.AuthError>.failure(AuthError: Unexpected error occurred with message: An unknown error occurred Recovery suggestion: This should not happen.

```
Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession { result in
    do {
      let session = try result.get()
      print(session.isSignedIn)
        let castSession = session as? AWSAuthCognitoSession
        print("cast session ", castSession)
      if let cognitoTokenProvider = session as? AuthCognitoTokensProvider {
      let tokens = try cognitoTokenProvider.getCognitoTokens().get()
          print("Token ", tokens)
      }

    } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

The isSignedIn value is true. the catch exception is thrown when I try to cast and retrieve the Cognito token

Comment: What error is thrown?  You shouldn't get any exceptions from conditional casts. Have you used the debugger?  What is the type of `session`?

Comment: @Paulw11 this is the error I'm getting.
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=5 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException, message=Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool.}), identityIdResult: Swift.Result<Swift.String, Amplify.AuthError>.failure(AuthError: Unexpected error occurred with message: An unknown error occurred

Comment: And when I print session this is what I get
Optional(AmplifyPlugins.AWSAuthCognitoSession(isSignedIn: true, userSubResult: Swift.Result<Swift.String, Amplify.AuthError>.failure(AuthError: Unexpected error occurred with message: An unknown error occurred Recovery suggestion: This should not happen. There is a possibility that there is a bug if this error persists

Comment: It looks like you have a configuration problem in your identity pool.  You can't get the token because authentication failed and there is no token to get.

Comment: Is there a way I can follow to get to the bottom of this issue and fix it

Answer (score 0):

In setting up amplify in my project I had to choose Cognito User Pool only. This solved my problem and I was able to retrieve the accessToken and the rest. Hope this helps someone someday cheers